# float is not working when children height are not equal

Tags: css

float is not working when any child element is greater than others.
Here is the jsfiddle.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/vs8bud2w/4/`
```

div2 is having height 120px;others have height 100px;So fifth element is not floating to left instead it stuck near div2.

How to fix this?
even clear both is not working.

Comment: Add a fixed min-height for each div.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can paste your code here.

Comment: use clear: left; on your element that doesn't float properly.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu that will solve the issue in this case.But I also have scenario like height is dynamic So you dont know which did has what height because height is determined based on response data.So how to solve that

Comment: @ManpreetMatharu min-height does not solve issue.

Comment: I solved it by giving parent flex:display and flex-wrap-:wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
.three {
   clear: left;
}
```

Meaning that no floating elements allowed on the left side.

Comment: that will solve the issue in this case.But I also have scenario like height is dynamic So you dont know which did has what height because height is determined based on response data.So how to solve that

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the hierarchy of your elements, `parent` holds `child`, which is divided into `one`, `two`, and `three`.
The `width:25%` of each child makes 4 elements take up the 100% width, hence the last element (child three, green) comes below them.

But since they are still contained within the parent `parent` div, it cannot float on top of another element that is already there, which is taking some place there (yellow with `height: 120px` ).

To make the green line up to the left, either make the height of all the elements equal, or put the green box (child three) outside the `parent` div.

Or you can also use the `clear: left` property for child three.